# SQL - 17003 Invalid column index fo the Query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have used the JDBC PrepareStatement for the query

```
SELECT count(1) Count FROM STDL_REPORT_OUTPUT WHERE RORDER = ?
```

But when I try to sent the value for the ? using

```
prep.setString(1, "1");
```

it throws:

> Invalid column index.  ORA-17003 SQLSTATE-99999
> 23:42:09,175 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
> 198543 [default task-2] ERROR stderr  - java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
> 23:42:09,176 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5741)
> 198544 [default task-2] ERROR stderr  -     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5741)
> 23:42:09,176 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5729)
> 198544 [default task-2] ERROR stderr  -     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5729)
> 23:42:09,177 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:289)
> 198545 [default task-2] ERROR stderr  -     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:289)
> 23:42:09,178 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setString(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:691)
> 198546 [default task-2] ERROR stderr  -     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setString(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:691)

Comment: Is the error coming from the `setString()` line (which should, it seems, get `setInt()` based on another comment, but that's not going to cause this error); or is it being thrown when you retrieve the count value later with `getInt()`, and the argument to that is wrong? You can edit your question to include the code around the fetch too, and indicate which line the exception refers to.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including the exception stacktrace.

Comment: I have attached the Error Message Please find some solution for this@Alex Poole

Comment: @mohit What is the datatype of `RORDER` column? And please execute the query from backend by passing a correct value. It's always better to provide full code snippet to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @Jacob Datatype of RORDER column is Number and i execute the query from backend it is working fine. 
and also i tired to use setInt

Comment: @mohit Have you tried using `setInt(1,1)`? Without double quotes. Please update your question with full code snippet.

Comment: Yes i tired both the ways @Jacob

Comment: @mohit Then provide us with full code snippet.

Comment: String sqlToTesstExistenceOfRecord = "SELECT count(1) Count FROM STDL_REPORT_OUTPUT WHERE RORDER = ?";
public void setString(int index, String value) throws SQLException {
  prep.setString(index, value);
  if(argList.size()>0)
  argList.remove(new Integer(index));
 }

Comment: @mohit You should edit the question and provide the code snippet. What is argList?

Comment: argsList is our LinkedList For our internal Use

Comment: Please edit your question to show a reasonable amount of code. We can't see the relationship between your String, and `prep` - we can't see whether that is actually used that in a prepared statement, or if it gets cleared somehow before your setString, or if you have a scope issue, etc. You're doing something wrong but without seeing your code we can't tell what.

Comment: By the way, the standard SQL expression for counting rows is `count(*)`. It won't make any difference, but standards are good :)

Answer (score 0):

The index used in the method [`setString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) starts from 1, not from 0, as explained in the linked javadoc:

> `parameterIndex` - **the first parameter is 1**, the second is 2, ...

Comment: I have set as 1 for index value and the datatype of the  column is NUMBER even i tired setInt still no use. @Davide Lorenzo